# why does pandas (python) import empty rows from excel although there is no data to follow

Tags: python, excel, pandas, anaconda

I'm looping over several Excel sheets and all but one are imported properly. The one loads an extra 16 empty rows although there is no other data on that sheet. The Excel tables that I load are similar in structure (same number of columns and same data structure) but the number of rows varies which is why I can't restrict those to just the 14 first ones in iloc. Any suggestions are welcome.

```
df = pd.read_excel(
        data, sheet_name=sheets
    )
    df = df.iloc[:, 0:11]
```

Comment: there probably is data below, but not something you can easily see (a text cell that's just space, a formatted but empty cell, etc)

Comment: Yeah, I figured something like that but "deleting" and reformatting the cells to default made no difference

Comment: I would use the `.dropna` method

Comment: That definitively removes those extra rows, unfortunately however, also any of my rows that contain NAs. But thanks for the suggestion

Comment: `dropna` accepts several parameters (`subset`, `how`) that should allow you to bend it to your will

Comment: Wonderful, thanks! `how="all"` solved it!